# How to login to a website with selenium that seems to detect selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to login to a credit card site to collect my transaction data.

I'm using selenium with python using Google Chrome & am rather stuck.

I am using non headless mode and can see my user/pass enter the fields correctly.

However when trying to click the submit button, selenium couldn't find the element.

So instead after entering the user/pw using selenium, I do:

`driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`

**This causes the automated browser to show "Waiting for " in google chrome,** however nothing happens. It appears to me that the website may be blocking selenium as when I use a non automated chrome, this works fine. I have no evidence for this though.

The website I'm trying to automate is: https://www.smbc-card.com/mem/index.jsp

What can I do to be able to login?

Version used: selenium==4.15.2
Python 3.11.6

I expected to see selenium login to the website. I've tried faking the user agent and trying different `time.sleep()` to stop the website sensing automation. I've also tried replicating the same inputs in a normal google chrome window and it works as expected.

Sample code:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537")


# TODO enable this to make headless
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.smbc-card.com/mem/index.jsp")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_input").send_keys(USER)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys(PASSWORD
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: For testing: Could you spin up an express server, replace `smbc-card.com...` with the url of the express server, and verify that you actually are getting the correct user-agent?

Comment: `127.0.0.1 - - [16/Nov/2023 08:56:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
ERROR:root:Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8`