# Did Edge version 119 break SeleniumBasic?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I use VBA/Selenium/Edge to automate several files. A couple weeks ago I was on version `118` of Edge/Edge Driver and everything worked. I came to work on a Monday and had Edge version `119`. Updated the Edge Driver to match, `119.0.2151.44`. Since then both Edge/Driver have been updated to `119.0.2151.58` and get the same error. The section of code it's getting hung up on is the maximizing of the window.

The error with or without `SwitchToNextWindow`:

```
 Run-time error '23':

 NoSuchWindowError
 Window not found: no such window: target window already closed
 from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge = 119.0.2151.58)
  (Driver info: msedgedriver = 119.0.2151.58  
  (33e26e7eb4fba096f2f29de91f90d34b8597be96),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19045 x86_64)
```

Visually what happens:
Small box opens to select username (handled by `SetCapability` so it goes away automatically.)
Edge window opens and shows a message that the user was selected.
The mouse moves to click OK on the message box
Error with code when attempting to maximize the window.
The Edge window remains open until/unless the module is ended.

The code:

```
Set oEdgeObject= CreateObject("Selenium.EdgeDriver")
    With oEdgeObject
    
    On Error GoTo SiteHandler

        .SetCapability "ms:edgeOptions", "{""excludeSwitches"":[""enable-automation""]}"
        .Start
        .Wait 1000

        Call LeftClick(600, 400)
        .Wait 1000
        
        .Window.Maximize
```

Attempted things:
Not using the `SetCapability` line to automatically select a profile.
Used `SwitchToNextWindow` (causes error, `window does not exist`)
Used `SwitchToPreviousWindow` (does not cause an error but does not resolve error either. Tried using it multiple times just in case it thought it was several windows again... didn't work.)
Tested code, as is, on another computer that still has Edge version `118`

Goal:
Open Edge, log the user in, maximize the window, execute the rest of the code.

Edit:
Attempted to use `get` with and without the `SetCapability`. The `SetCapability` automatically logs in, and when I manually select the profile it does the same thing. Opens up a normal looking Edge window and says X user has logged in, and gives the same error.
Attempted to use `get` without `SetCapability` and without selecting a profile manually. Clicking `F8` through to the `get` command opened the website in the small pseudo-Edge window. The window cannot be maximized and doesn't have an address bar, and I assume lacks multiple other things. Unfortunately I'm too new to be able to post an image.

Edit Version:
`SeleniumBasic-2.0.9.0`
Updated to Edge/Driver version `119.0.2151.72`
Yes I mean the Edge profile when I say log the user in.
I've tried multiple URLs. By default I have a variable that fills out with a website based on which module I'm running. I've tried manually filling the variable out with the Google address. Same result each time.

Edit:
Been updating driver when the browser updates. Had very low results with
`SwitchToParentFrame`
`SwitchToWindowByName`
`SwitchToWindowByTitle`.
I pulled up the Locals window and rarely with random combinations of the above three it would retain the window and allow it to used like it used to. More consistently if I get rid of the `SetCapability` and I slowly select Sign In then Continue manually it will open the website and maximize it normally. The problems with this are that it makes it more manual, due to the timing aspect gives it more chances for human error, and it brings back the info bar that says Edge is being controlled by test software. Most sites it's not a problem but there's one that is used multiple times that it will cause troubles since things are shifted on the screen. It seems to be losing track of the window with the sign in process. If done with correct timing manually it will work but with the above issues. If done automatically it skips the user login too quickly and forgets that the next window that opens was from the `.start` command.

Comment: include the exception that occurs when you don't attempt to switch the window.

Comment: try using a .get() before maximizing and see if the same error is still thrown.

Comment: Probably something happened recently: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77488688/8941307

Comment: @pcalkins Updated with more test results.

Comment: @Pieterjan thank you for the link. It looks like that person is able to get their Chrome to open up normally. Unfortunately getting Edge to do the same is the problem I'm stuck at at the moment.

I can't add comments on their thread but it looks like they're missing a closing parenthesis for their `.send_keys(PASSWORD` line

Comment: According to my test (my Edge version 119.0.2151.58, selenium version 4.15.0), I was able to open the Edge, log my profile and maximize the window.
To narrow down the issue, I want to check some things：
1. Which version of selenium are you using?
2. Does "log the user in" refer to your edge profile?
3. Do you have a specific url to access?

Comment: @Elin Lu updated post and question title to be more specific. SeleniumBasic-2.0.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 2 is not supported now, we recommend you update to the latest version of [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) (selenium 4 or later) to see if this issue persists.

Comment: Thank you for the response and apologies on the delay. I was out last week and playing catch-up so far this week. 

I'm trying to get IT to assist with getting the newer version of Selenium installed but it's a process. In the meantime I've tried some more things to mixed results and updated the original post.

What would I need to download from the link that you provided to be able to continue using VBA, or would I have to switch to another language?

Comment: Unfortunately, vba language can only be supported in selenium2.
In order to create scripts that interact with the Selenium Server (Remote WebDriver) or create local Selenium WebDriver scripts, you need to make use of language-specific client drivers. Selenium4 requirements by language：C#,Ruby,Python, JavaScript, Java

Comment: Dang that sucks to hear but thank you for letting me know. While waiting for IT I had pre-emptively downloaded the Selenium 4.15.0 for Java since I already have a tool for creating/running Java. Stupid question but once I do get IT assistance should I be running all 36 Executable Jar Files from the main download folder, and all 24 Lib folder Executable Jar Files to get it to work properly? I would assume I don't need the 2 Safari or 2 Firefox since we don't use either but maybe run them just in case. Not sure exactly what all the other ones do. Thank you for all your help.